# Block local holidays and sundays at the native date-picker of HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker, native

As far as possible, avoid using third party resources and prefer native. For a project, I need the native HTML5 `<input type="date">` with local vacations and blocked Sundays.

Many third-party components/plugins allow them to spend the holidays, but do not use the native date-picker, but are customized. I prefer the native not to have to deal with the Browser and the device being used (desktop, Android or iOS).

I will use `min="xxxx-xx-xx"` and `max="xxxx-xx-xx"` to establish the range of days available to choose, but is it possible to block specific days within that range or do I have to use the resource of a third?

Comment: You are talking about `<input type="date">`? No, that is not possible, there are no attributes that would allow for anything like this.

Comment: It was what feared me but I needed to know if it was possible in some way that I ignore.